# inserting thousands of rows at once to database in Postgresql

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

Ive recently started learning python and sql and Ive been messing around with this for days and am stuck. Im trying to insert in my Postgresql database table 10 000 generated rows that includes id, address, booleanStatement, integerStatement and addressDate.

I created an addressGenerator and it gives me results in a form:

```
myAddresses = addressGenerator (10000, 0)
print(myAddresses)
```

Output: `['M3-44-44-00-00-00', False, 1],...,[M3-44-44-00-27-f5, False, 1]`

Now to insert it in database I wrote the following code:

```
conn.psycopg2.connect("user=abc password=abc dbname=abc host=localhost")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('INSERT INTO "my-table" (id, "my-address", integerStatement, booleanStatement, addressDate) Values (NULL, %%s, %%d, %%s, %%s)', myAddresses)
conn.commit()
```

It gives me error: `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "%"`

The way I understand it: id is autoincremented, so the placeholder can be NULL, my-address, booleanStatement are strings(%%s), integerStatement is %%d and addressDate that is timestamp is also %%s. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why `%%s`…?! http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Saw it in some other question.., if I use %s it gives me "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: That's a different error which is due to you specifying 4 placeholders but apparently only providing 3 values for them.

Comment: Does it mean that with auto incremented "id" column I dont have to include it when I want to insert other column values?

Comment: @Inzzza8 exactly: omit `id` from the query entirely (remove both column name and value)

Comment: @Bohemian Thank you, I did that, now I still seem to have problem with the timestamp column. How can I leave it blank so I could update it later? By using Null or Default it still gives me the same "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"